# How to Read a JSON file,and change some values and write the json in to new file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object

Example:
Before:

```
{ 
    "firstName": "CSS", 
    "lastName": "HTML", 
    "isAlive": true, 
    "age": 5, 
    "height_cm": 111.12, 

}
```

After:

```
{ 
    "firstName": "JAVA", 
    "lastName": "nodeJS", 
    "isAlive": true, 
    "age": 5, 
    "height_cm": 111.12, 

}
```

I want to make changes in Json object(firstname and lastname) and save it into to onother Json file

Answer (score 1):

Could be done like that:

```
var fs = require("fs");

// read
var content = fs.readFileSync("./before.json", "utf-8");
var object = JSON.parse(content);

// change
object.firstName = "JAVA";
object.lastName = "nodeJS";

// write
var newContent = JSON.stringify(object, null, 4);
fs.writeFileSync("./after.json", newContent, "utf-8");
```

Note: A prettier approach would use `readFile` and `writeFile` instead of their synchronous versions, but this shows the general idea in a cleaner way.